# What does this statement actually mean?

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed. If $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ is any bounded function, then the set $B = \{ x \in E : o(f,x) \geq \epsilon \}$ is **closed** for every $\epsilon > 0$
>
> Here $o(f,x)$ is defined as the **oscillation** of $f$ where we have
>
> $$o(f,a) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} M(f) - m(f)$$
>
> where $M(f) = \sup \{f(x) : x \in Q, |x - a| < \delta  \}$ and $m(f) = \inf \{f(x) : x \in Q, |x - a| < \delta  \}$

I've read the proof of this statement, but after reading it, I wasn't sure what this statement actually tells me. The preceding theorem states that we get continuity of $f$ if $o(f,x) = 0$, this seems to make sense to me and a good reason to prove it. But as for this one, I am not understanding what $B$ being closed here has to do with anything. He used this result later in chapter 3 in integration, but apart from that I don't know why he put this here. I just don't see what this has to do with anything he discussed about before.

This was adapted from M.Spivak Calculus on Manifolds.

Comment: Thank you for that, edited.

Comment: Seen your edit, now it's much clearer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what does $B_\epsilon$ even mean? For a given $f$ as you have described, $B_\epsilon$ is the set of points in $E$ where the discontinuity jump is greater than $\epsilon$. The intuition for $o(f,a)$ is that it expresses the size of the discontinuity of $f$ at a point $a$. Hence, if we want to express all of the points in the domain where the discontinuity is significant (I.E. larger than $\epsilon$), we construct the set $B_\epsilon$ which is exactly the points in the domain at which the discontinuity of $f$ is larger than $\epsilon$.

Second: Why is this result important? This result is important because it helps us to prove Lebesgue's theorem, which is indispensable in the theory of Reimmann integration. This theorem says that a function is reimmann integrable if and only if it's set of discontinuities has measure 0.

Third: What does $D_\epsilon$ being closed have to do with the proof of lebesgue's theorem?

If  $f: U \subset \subset \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function on a bounded set $U$, then inparticular, since $B_\epsilon$ is closed for every $\epsilon$, we have that for every $\epsilon$, $D_\epsilon \subset U$ is a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so by Heine-Borel it is compact. Compactness of $D_\epsilon$ allows us to take any arbitrary (possibly uncountable) open cover $\{ U_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in I}$ of $D_\epsilon$ and find a finite subcover of $U_\alpha$. This allows us to cover $D_\epsilon$ with a finite number of boxes of arbitrarily small volume. From here, we can prove Lebesgues theorem.

Comment: I am actually asking what does the set $B$ even mean?

Comment: ah yes. I'll edit. one second.

Comment: I want to ask a question relating to $(3)$ and $(1)$. Why is $B_\epsilon$ being closed an important result here then? Or is this really just a small lemma to help the bigger result, and nothing more?

Comment: It's not really an important result. Exactly like you said, it's just a lemma leading up to proving lebesgue's theorem.